# $C^1$ functions have weak derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

How can one prove, for $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open:

> $f \in C^1 \implies$ $\partial_i f$ are the weak derivatives of $f$, $i=1,...,n$?

I think one should use the divergence theorem for $C^1$ functions. However, this may not be a completely trivial thing, because the divergence theorem applies to smooth enough boundaries.

The proof I have in mind goes like this:

- fix $\phi \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$, let $K \subset \subset \Omega$
- find an open set $V$ with smooth enough boundary, with $K \subseteq V \subseteq \Omega$
- apply the divergence theorem: $$\int_\Omega \phi \partial_ifd x=\int_V \phi \partial_ifd x=\int_{\partial V}\phi f \nu_id\sigma-\int_V \partial_i \phi f d x=-\int_V \partial_i \phi f d x=-\int_\Omega \partial_i\phi fd x$$

Problems: what is smooth enough? Can I, and how do I find such a $V$?

Comment: Why do you think you need to have divergence theorem? Doesn't it follow directly from definition of weak derivative, that for a $C^1$-Function weak derivative is equal to strong derivative?

Comment: Here is my definition of weak derivative: $\partial_i f \in L^1_{loc}$ is a weak derivative of $f \in L^1_{loc}$ if for every $\phi \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ the integration by parts holds. Why should $C^1$ functions have weak derivatives from this definition?

Comment: @Fakemistake Can you provide a reference for this formula? I think that it is based on the divergence theorem (which cannot be in general applied to any open set $\Omega$) and that the term $f \phi|_{\partial \Omega}$ should be replaced by an integral on the boundary.

Comment: This is simply partial integration

Comment: @Fakemistake You're right, it's the divergence theorem under another name, essentially. Anyhow, if you could provide reference for this result for arbitrary open sets it would be great :)

Comment: Ok, [this on page 1](https://isem.math.kit.edu/images/5/5b/AppendixD.pdf) is slight different, but covers what you want imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to find such $V$?** Consider the function
$$
g(x) = \frac{d(x,K)}{d(x,K)+d(x,\Omega^c)},
$$
where $d(x,A)$ denotes the distance from $x$ to $A$. One could define the intermediate open set $K \subseteq V \Subset \Omega$ as $V = \{ x : g(x) < \frac 12 \}$, but it wouldn't necessarily be smooth.

To fix this, consider a smooth approximation $g_\varepsilon$ (e.g., given by convolution) and let $V_t := \{ x : g_\varepsilon(x) < t \}$. Again, $K \subseteq V_t \Subset \Omega$ for $t$ close to $\frac 12$. But now, Sard's theorem implies that $\partial V_t = g^{-1}(t)$ is smooth for almost all $t$, so one can choose the right value for $t$.

$\newcommand{\dd}{\,d}$

---

**Why is it unnecessary?**

1. For each ball $B_r(x) \subseteq \Omega$, the classical derivatives $\partial_i f$ are also weak derivatives (the set is smooth, so there's no problem in integrating by parts). Since being a weak derivative is a local notion (which is seen by partition of unity) and $\Omega$ is covered by such balls, the same is true for the whole $\Omega$.
2. If we insist on a direct argument, let us mimic the proof of the divergence formula. Pick any $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. Aiming at the equality
   $$
   \int_\Omega \partial_i f \varphi \dd x = - \int_\Omega f \partial_i \varphi \dd x,
   $$
   let us denote $I(x_1,\ldots,\hat{x_i},\ldots,x_n) = \{ t \in \mathbb{R} : (x_1,\ldots,t,\ldots,x_n) \in \Omega \}$ - the slice of $\Omega$ given by fixing all coordinates except $x_i$. For simplicity, denote the vector of these $n-1$ coordinates by $x'$ and identifiy $(x_1,\ldots,x_i,\ldots,x_n)$ with $(x',x_i)$. Then by Fubini:
   \begin{align*}
   \int_\Omega \partial_i f \varphi \dd x + \int_\Omega f \partial_i \varphi \dd x
   & = \int_\Omega \partial_i (f(x) \varphi(x)) \dd x \\
   & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \int_{I(x')} \partial_t (f(x',t) \varphi(x',t)) \dd t \dd x' \\
   & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \left[ f(x',t) \varphi(x',t) \right]_{\partial I(x')} \dd x' \\
   & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} 0 \dd x' = 0.
   \end{align*}
   For each $x' \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, we only deal with a $1$-dimensional slice $I(x')$, and since $\varphi$ has a compact support, the function $f \varphi$ is identically zero in a neighborhood of $I(x')$. This is why everything vanishes.